# WSO2 4.6.0 - unable to install CA certificate. Always falling back to default certificate

Tags: certificate, esb, wso2

We are trying to install a third party CA cert on our WSO2 ESB server (Linux). We are unable to install CA certificate. Always falling back to default certificate.

While the WSO2 service is started, it shows that the new cert is being referred and loaded, but at client browser, it gives error and shows the default inbuilt cert.

Can someone guide us to where we need to look for errors?

We followed the instructions from 
http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products

All steps are followed correctly,

Answer (score 0):

Sreejith, the document you're following is correct. I've used the same to configure our servers.

you can get the certificate being used by your server by executing this from a consumer host (client):

`echo -n | openssl s_client -connect esb.yourdomain.co.nz:8243 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > certificate.cert`

Then you can see if the certificate being used is the one you expect.

To replace the default certificate, you'll need to replace the `WSO_HOME$/repository/resources/security/wsocarbon.jks` keystore and modify `WSO2_HOME$/repository/conf/carbon.xml` and `$WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml` with the new keystore (along with alias and passwords) whenever necessary.

According with my experience the keystore need to be **replaced**. You can **not** simply add your certificate to the existent keystore, you need to force wso2 server to use your certificate by making it the **only** certificate in the keystore. Also the certificate CN and alias must match your server hostname (as in the url) for this to work.

Then add the certificate to the `WSO_HOME$/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks` keystore.

And don't forget to restart the server after the changes.

Regards